# Jupyter-notebook dataframe last column

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Hello I have a data frame in python jupyter notebook and need to take the last column of it. How Can I take the last column of data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Use iloc index, it should do the trick 
`df.iloc[:,-1]`

It works on such way that `:` selects all rows and `-1` selects last column